# access static class from asp.net form

Tags: c#, asp.net, eval

I am using <%# MyFormatClass(Eval("fieldname")) %> to display data in a grid view on my page. MyFormatClass works fine, but now I want to move it to a central location that can be used by many pages. When I try to access the class <%# Utils.MyFormatClass(Eval("fieldname")) %> it no longer works. Is this something we are allowed to do?

Comment: Is this a Web Site "project" created with File->New Web Site, or a Web Application Project, created with File->New Project?

Comment: What you're trying to do is perfectly legal, you'll need to post some more code/more info about what doesn't work.

Comment: It's a web application project in VS 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't provide much information this is just a guess, but maybe you need simply to put your `Utils` class in your App_Code folder; all the code there will be compiled to an assembly that is available to all your pages.